# Android Development - Get mass of device being used

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, android-layout-weight

I am making an app that requires me to detect the distance traveled by the device. The way I will do it is by using the accelerometer to get the newtons in which the device is subjected to. I will use this formula to get the distance:

`Distance (m) = Newtons (N) * Seconds (s) * Mass (Kg)`

I am easily able to get newtons and Seconds but I'm not sure about getting mass. I had the idea of dividing the newtons that gravity exerts on the device by usual gravity (`9.8 N / Kg`) and get the mass that way but I don't know if it would be reliable. Anyone know? Thanks in advance!

P.S. If you need more explanation, by all means ask me!!

Comment: You really don't need the mass. The accelerometer will give you an acceleration, not a force, and you can use `a` to determine distance independent of mass.

Comment: Indeed, you do not need the mass.  But the rapid accumulation of inevitable errors will mean you cannot *meaningfully* integrate acceletation to determine distance.  This has been covered here many times before.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice! I still want to try it just for fun. So accelerometer give m/s/s im guessing?

Comment: Are you sure your formula `Distance (m) = Newtons (N) * Seconds (s) * Mass (Kg)` is correct in the first place? Since `1N = 1Kg*m/s^2`, then your formula would suggest `kg^2 = s`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry misspelt it. It's actually `Distance (m) = Newtons (N) * Seconds ^ 2 (s) * Mass (Kg)` Doesn't matter anymore anyways, it was covered that accelerometers use m/s^2 not neutons